# NERDTree opens by default if opening a directory

Tags: vim, macvim, nerdtree

If I open a folder in vim like this:

```
$ mvim . # or vim .
```

NERDTree opens by default in full width:

[image]

How can I prevent this from happening and show default VIM welcome screen instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are explicitly telling vim to start with a listing of the current directory, if you don't want that, just do `$ vim`.

Answer (score 1):

Run `vim` to get the Welcome Screen.

If you open `vim .` you'll get a directory listing of the current working directory (Netrw or NERDTree Directory Listing).

NERDTree overrides the default file browser (netrw).
To disable directory listing by NERDTree at startup, add `let g:NERDTreeHijackNetrw=0` to your ".vimrc".
This [Option](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERD_tree.txt) tells NERD tree whether to replace the netrw autocommands for exploring local directories. 
Run `vim --noplugin .` and you see an empty buffer.